# Implementing CSRF tokens in post routes with Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, csrf

Hi I have just started to get into learning Node.js and trying to build a REST API. By my understanding to return a jwt token for user login its good practice to also combine the use of csrf tokens, as well as in any other form data.

Now i have this code here:

```
//Packages
const { required } = require("@hapi/joi");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const csrf = require("csurf");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

//Middleware
const csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true });
const parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

//Models
const UserModel = require("../Models/Users");

//Validaiton Schemas
const UserValidations = require("../Validations/userValidationSchemas");

//Security Functions
const passwords = require("../Security/hashing");

//Handlers
const UserState = require("../Handlers/UserState");

router.get("/", csrfProtection, (req, res) => {
   res.send("users");
});

router.get("/userById/:userId", csrfProtection, async (req, res) => {
   try {
      const user = await UserModel.findOne({ _id: req.params.userId });
      res.send(user);
   } catch (error) {
      return res.status(400).send(error);
   }
});

//Create new User

router.post("/newUser", async (req, res) => {
   //validate submitted data to match to schema

   const { error } = UserValidations.newUserValidationSchema(req.body);

   if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0]).message;

   //check for existing user with same email

   const emailExists = await UserModel.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
   if (emailExists) return res.status(400).send("Email already exists");

   //hash password

   const hashedPassword = await passwords.hashPassword(req.body.password);
   if (hashedPassword == null)
      return res
         .status(400)
         .send("Password could not be hashed as invalid format provided");

   //If all is good create the new user
   const UserData = new UserModel({
      title: req.body.title,
      name: req.body.name,
      surname: req.body.surname,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword
   });

   try {
      const saveUser = await UserData.save();
      res.send(saveUser);
   } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).send(error);
   }
});

//Auth login

router.post("/auth-login", async (req, res) => {
   //Validate data before we check it against db
   const { error } = UserValidations.authUserLoginValidationSchema(req.body);

   if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0]).message;

   //check if such user exists
   const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
   if (!user) return res.status(400).send("No such user exists");

   const checkPassword = await passwords.comparePassword(
      req.body.password,
      user.password,
      UserState.LogUserIn,
      user,
      req.body.remember_user
   );
});

/*
    TODO user update
    TODO user logged tokens
    */

module.exports = router;
```

And how is it that with GET routes csrf tokens are fine but when implemented to POST, it complains with an *Invalid token'?

When i try to test and debug with postman it does the crying? Also is which is best practice to save the jwt token in the headers or the cookie/session?